# OpenCV VideoWriter errors on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, macports

I'm trying this code:

```
//[Code omitted ...]
Mat outputframe (frame1.rows*2, frame1.cols*4,CV_8UC3);
VideoCapture myvideo(path);
VideoWriter outputVideo;
outputVideo.open(outputName, CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT, myvideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),(outputframe.size()),true);
//[Code omitted:Start cycling on the video and]
Mat elaboratedFrame(frame1.rows*2, frame1.cols*4,CV_8UC3)
//[Code omitted:Elaborating the frame "elaboratedFrame"]
elaboratedFrame.copyTo(outputframe);
outputVideo<< outputframe;
//[Code omitted ...]
```

I'm on a Mac (OSX Lion and OpenCV 2.4.6 installed via macports) and everytime I try to run the code I get:
1) On the line where I open outputvideo:

> WARNING: Could not create empty movie file container.

2) When I run the program I get this error on the line of the VideoWriter:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dst.data == dst0.data) in cvCvtColor

OR (if I try using `cvtColor(elaboratedFrame, outputframe, CV_GRAY2RGB);`

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor

The program obviusly doesn't create anything and **nothing changes** if I chose another codec (MP4,MPEG,MJPG,FFMPEG ecc). I'm getting mad on this error. Anyone who has issued the same problem and maybe solved it?
Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: I solved the warinng problem: it was due to an error during the creation of the destination path for the video. Still remains the problem 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I made many mistakes:

1) `Mat outputframe (frame1.rows*2, frame1.cols*4,CV_8UC3);`
I have frame1 actual information in a line after this declaration. This caused the

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dst.data == dst0.data) in cvCvtColor

2) I made a mistake in creating the right file path for the file. This caused the

> WARNING: Could not create empty movie file container.

3) The last assertion was an error of the `cvtColor(elaboratedFrame, outputframe, CV_GRAY2RGB);` which was wrong